# jQuery: ignore 3rd party content when waiting for window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ready

I'm using the following jQuery code to remove a loading animation when the website has finished loading all content, including images.

```
$(window).one("load", function() {
   $("#loader").remove();
});
```

However; if I have google maps on the page and the internet connection is slow, the loading overlay takes 40+ seconds to hide, simply because Google Maps has not finished loading.

Question: How can I ignore 3rd party content such as Google Maps and iframes when waiting for website to load with jQuery? I want to hide the overlay even if google maps and iframes haven't loaded yet.

Comment: Have you tried using `.ready()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code instead:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $("#loader").remove();
});
```

The difference is that this code will execute once all `HTML` elements are loaded and the `DOM` is ready. While `window.load` executes after all content are loaded like images and iframes.

You can read more about `$(document).ready` vs. `$(window).load` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/632672/JavaScripts-document-ready-vs-window-load).

edit:

If you want to wait for images to load just use this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("img").one("load", function () {
        $("#loader").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I know about this, I want to wait for images though.